# Get original values of the model with angularJS after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I used to get the original values of the model with `this.model.changed` or `this.model._previousAttributes` using BackboneJS.

I want to use the same function with angular, by detecting all the changes in the model set by text fields, checkbox, not in one text textField like the case with `ng-change`.

I tried to use it in the div of `form` but in vain.

I also tried to use :

```
 $scope.policyL = savingsDraft.fromServer();
    $scope.$watch('policyL', function (oldV, newV) {
 });
```

but it didn't work too.

Example of my view code :

```
form(role='form', ng-change='changed (policy, newP)' novalidate)
  .row
    .col-sm-4.form-group
      label.control-label Taux de rendement
      input.form-control(type='number',
        min=0,
        max=1,
        ng-model='policy.admin.depEarnRate')
    .col-sm-4.form-group
      label.control-label Frais de contrat
      input.form-control(type='number',
        min=0,
        ng-model='policy.admin.feesIni')
```

and in my controller :

```
$scope.accept = function () {
     $scope.change = function();
};
```

PS: I want to get the original model after clicking on the button accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could make a copy upon controller instantiation. Then whenever the $watch is fired, compare the current model with the copy. If it's different, take the value from the copy.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a form, it's a good practice to keep a copy of the original data. You can easily reset back to the master copy if needed.

```
$scope.master = dataModel;
$scope.dataModel = angular.copy($scope.master);


$scope.reset = function () {
    $scope.dataModel = angular.copy($scope.master);
    $scope.yourForm.$setPristine();
};
```

Then, if you really want to get only the changes from the master, I took Backbone's `changedAttributes` function and modified it to work with our case here.

```
var changedAttributes = function(master, diff) {
    if (!diff) return false;
    var changed = {};
    for (var attr in diff) {
        var val = diff[attr];
        if (!_.isEqual(master[attr], val)) changed[attr] = val;
    }
    return _.size(changed) ? changed : false;
},
```

To use this:

```
var changes = changedAttributes($scope.master, $scope.dataModel);
if (changes) console.log("dataModel is different from master");
```

To include underscore in an angular app, [angular-underscore](https://github.com/floydwch/angular-underscore) seems to work great.